# Problem while handling missing data, can't reproduce my result as desired

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python. I was working with some data and I encountered some missing data. What I wanted to do was fill some of them with mean and some of them with mode while also dropping some of the columns.

Here what I am doing

```
missing_val_count = (train.isnull().sum())
print(missing_val_count[missing_val_count > 0])


Output:
LotFrontage      259
Alley           1369
MasVnrType         8
MasVnrArea         8
BsmtQual          37
BsmtCond          37
BsmtExposure      38
BsmtFinType1      37
BsmtFinType2      38
Electrical         1
FireplaceQu      690
GarageType        81
GarageYrBlt       81
GarageFinish      81
GarageQual        81
GarageCond        81
dtype: int64
```

I have this many columns with missing data.

```
train['MasVnrType'].fillna(train['MasVnrType'].replace('NA', None), inplace = True)
train['MasVnrArea'].fillna(train['MasVnrArea'].replace('NA', '0'), inplace = True)

features = ['LotFrontage', 'GarageYrBlt']
for i in features:
    train[i].fillna(train[i].mean(), inplace = True)

features1 = ['Electrical', 'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'FireplaceQu', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond']

for i in features1:
    train[i].fillna(train[i].mode()[0], inplace = True)

train = train.drop(columns = ['Alley'])

missing_val_count = (train.isnull().sum())
print(missing_val_count[missing_val_count > 0])
```

When I run this code, am getting

```
MasVnrType         8
MasVnrArea         8
dtype: int64
```

I am not able to work with these 2 columns. What am I doing wrong or I am missing something?

Comment: I think you forgot to add `axis=0` into your `fillna()`.

Comment: Tried it, not working.

Comment: I think you have to loop over the lists features and features1 and then use the fillna method to fill the nan values of every column individually.

Comment: Don't use fillna with inplace=True. It does not work as you expected.

Comment: Hey Pramote, thanks for helping. Can you please explain a bit more, I mean for the 'MasVnrType' and 'MasVnrArea' columns of my dataset. I am still not able to handle those missing data

Comment: The first two lines did not do anything. Check the code below.

Comment: Looping is not a good idea.  In some circumstances, it can lead to poor performance.

Comment: Thanks Pramote, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
train['MasVnrType'].replace('NA', None, inplace=True)
train['MasVnrArea'].replace('NA', '0', inplace=True)

features = ['LotFrontage', 'GarageYrBlt']
train[features] = train[features].fillna(train[features].mean())

features1 = ['Electrical', 'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'FireplaceQu', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond']
train[features1] = train[features1].fillna(train[features1].mode())
```

Or

```
values = train[features].mean().to_dict()
train.fillna(values, inplace=True)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, np.nan, 3], 'B': [10, 20, np.nan], 'C': [100, 200, 'NA']}) 
df['C'].replace('NA', 0, inplace=True)
```

Output

```
     A     B    C
0  1.0  10.0  100
1  NaN  20.0  200
2  3.0   NaN    0
```

Another:

```
features = ['A', 'B']   
value = df[features].mean().to_dict()
df.fillna(value, inplace=True)
```

Output

```
     A     B    C
0  1.0  10.0  100
1  2.0  20.0  200
2  3.0  15.0    0
```

Comment: The first two will work with inplace=True.  For the rest, you have to pass a dictionary to make it work. train.fillna({'LotFrontage': tain['LotFrontage'].mean() }, inplace=True)

Comment: Tried not working with inplace = True, just having problem with the first two, rest of them are working

Comment: Which lines did you try?

Comment: Okay, got it so the issue was I was not subscripting it
Works fine if it's
train['MasVnrType'].fillna(train['MasVnrType'].replace('NA', 'None')[0], inplace = True)
train['MasVnrArea'].fillna(train['MasVnrArea'].replace('NA', '0')[0],inplace = True)

Missed the [0] in those specific lines

Comment: It is not what you want to do. You will mess up other values. You want to replace 'NA' value with None. Your code does not do that, Do you want to fillna with the first value of that column?

Comment: i converted the features and features1 to dictionary, and then filled their missing values with mean and mode, in the MasVnrType' and 'MasVnrArea' I subscriptaed them to 0 and replaced them with None and 0 respectively

Comment: If you want to replace 'NA' with None for MasVnrType and 'NA' with 0 for MasVnrArea. Use the code above assuming that the value is text 'NA'. Subscripting [0] mean the first value. It is not what you want.  If the value is NaN, train['MasVnrType'].fillna('None, inplace=True)

Comment: Yeah Okay, Very Thanks Pramote